# How do I stop ActiveRecord looking for a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to create an ActiveRecord model called 'Search' without a table. I keep getting this error when I do @search = Search.new.

sql::Error: Table 'searchdemo_development.tablelesses' doesn't exist: SELECT * FROM `tablelesses`

I am using the idea from this comment: [Rails model without database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315850/rails-model-without-database/318919#318919). I also get the same kind of error doing the basic:

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

How do I get ActiveRecord stop looking for a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a few reasons you *might* want to do something like this.  Perhaps you want to leverage some of the non-db-related methods on ActiveRecord or you want to pass your object to something that expects and ActiveRecord instance.  Without more info, it is impossible to say whether the choice to use AR here is correct or incorrect.

In any event, if you want to continue on this path...

check out this Railscast
http://railscasts.com/episodes/121-non-active-record-model

and also checkout this gem:
http://github.com/kennethkalmer/activerecord-tableless-models/tree/master

Comment: What I'm trying to do is similar to http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form except I don't want to save searches to a database or even have a table for the model.

Answer (score 0):

Why in the name of the lord would you want an actve record model without a table? The purpose of an active record model is to communicate with a database. I assume that it is impossible to have an active record model without a db table.

Perhaps you want a regular class?

```
class Search
  # your methods here
end
```

Comment: I agree that it seems a strange use of the ActiveRecord pattern to have a class without a table, but in fact the validations provided by Rails' implementation of ActiveRecord are still useful for model data that you may not want to persist. And it's certainly not impossible to do.

Comment: If you want validations, there's a gem for that which is not related to Rails or Active Record. I don't rememeber the name, but I guess you'll find it on rubyforge. Or you can write your own ; ) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775976

Comment: Oh, and hopefully this will change in Rails 3.0, with ActiveModel. `include ActiveModel::Validations`, have lunch. =D