# Is it possible to have validations for basic_model (couchdb) in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, couchdb

is it possible to use validations like:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name, :title  
  validates_length_of :title, :minimum => 5 
end
```

with [basic_model](http://github.com/topfunky/basic_model/tree/master)?

I tried reading the source, but I couldn't find anything there. Are those `validates_` available for other model types, or only ActiveRecord::Base?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The validations in ActiveRecord are very coupled with ActiveRecord itself, so you won't be able to easely use AR's validation code outside of AR. They're well aware of this, and Rails 3.0 will have ActiveModel, which decouples it from ActiveRecord, so that you could have done something like this:

```
class Foo
  include ActiveModel::Validations
end
```

Until then, you could [write your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775976#776220) or use the [validatable](http://validatable.rubyforge.org/) gem.